# What encryption is used with RMStore and how to upload an App using it to the App Store correctly?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval, rmstore

When uploading an application with iTunes Connect Apple asks you to specify if your application is using any encryption features.

Under what conditions does **RMStore** use **encryption** and how should one answer these questions when uploading an App to the App Store.

[image: screenshot]

Note : I am using the cocoapods to get **RMStore**

[image: screenShotEncryption]

Comment: How did you end up submitting @tibor-udvari? Which options did you select and was it approved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*tl;dr: Some optional components of RMStore use encryption indirectly (the Keychain) or to decrypt data (the app receipt). In my opinion, both usages qualify as exemptions of the U.S. Export Administration Regulations.*

The RMStore core does not use encryption. However, there are two optional components that do:

1. `RMStoreKeychainPersistence`: Uses the keychain to store purchase information. While the information is provided to the keychain unencrypted, the keychain itself uses encryption.
2. `RMStoreAppReceiptVerificator` and `RMAppReceipt`: Uses OpenSSL to decrypt the app receipt.

Apple asks you the following:

> Is your app designed to use cryptography or does it contain or
>   incorporate cryptography? (Select Yes even if your app is only
>   utilizing the encryption available in iOS or OS X.)

For each case:

1. It depends on your interpretation of "using cryptography". I'd argue that no, your app is not using cryptography in this case.
2. Yes. This leads to the following question:

> Does your app qualify for any of the exemptions provided in Category
>   5, Part 2 of the U.S. Export Administration Regulations?

I believe the answer is *Yes*. The way I see it, parsing the encrypted app receipt provided by Apple qualifies as at least one of the following exemptions:

- Limited to intellectual property and copyright protection
- Limited to authentication, digital signature, or the decryption of data or files
- Specially designed and limited for banking use or "money transactions"

**It should be noted that as long as you're decrypting the app receipt, you would have to answer these questions the same way, RMStore or not.**

Also, you should consult this with your lawyer. I certainly will.

[image]

Comment: Disclaimer: I wrote RMStore.